# How to change ComboBox.SelectedItem on changing ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ComboBox

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

On changing ItemsSource I can get an error in SelectedItem, because there is no SelectedItem in new ItemsSource. I am need to change SelectedIndex to 0 on ItemsSource changing.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What if before changing the ItemsSource you set it's selected index to -1  and then set the source.

```
combo.SelectedIndex = -1;
combo.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: I don't want to use code behinds. Is there any xaml methods or may be anything like a validate rule?

Comment: `SelectedIndex` goes automatically to -1 whenever `ItemsSource` is assigned a new value.

Comment: Binding value is a ValueType. It Is not support the null value.